# Can't change from NSWindow controller to TableViewController via storyboard (OXS - swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift2

Trying to change from a sign up NSWindowcontroller to a TableViewController when the user is verified. Code is below -

```
func signup() {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        let windowcontroller:NSTableView = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("table") as! NSTableView
            })
}
```

However the following error appears.

Could not cast value of type 'NSWindowController' (0x7fff79b0bf78) to 'NSTableView' (0x7fff79aff458).